# Matching string using levenshtein distance and euristics

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance

I have string patterns ('rules'), in 'categories'. e.g.:

**Category1**

- lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
- consectetur adipiscing elit
- fusce sit amet ante nisi
- lorem ut sem interdum molestie
- suspendisse non lorem ut sem interdum molestie

**Category2**

- vivamus porta non metus egestas finibus
- nam convallis augue nec laoreet pretium
- turpis velit cursus enim ac suscipit risus turpis in metus

Now, I want to be able to 'categorize' a string based on those rules. Let's say we want to find out which category the string `fusce laoreet amet ante nisi` belongs to. My current implementation will use `levenshtein distance` implementation and find out that the string mostly 'looks like' `fusce sit amet ante nisi` and hence, the category is `Category1`.

Let's say we want to categorize `vivamus vel lorem imperdiet sit`. Because I put threshold 1/5th of the string length (i.e. the string must be at least 80% similar to its match) on the `levenshtein distance` algo, the string will remain 'uncategorized'.

In such case I would continue with the following algorithm ...

From each category, I will extract the 'common words' - i.e. words which repeat between the rules within the category. In way, those are the dominating words in the category. So, we'll have:

**Category1**

- lorem: 3
- sit: 2
- amet: 2
- sem: 2
- interdum: 2
- molestie: 2

**Category2**

- metus: 2
- turpis: 2

Now I will split the `vivamus vel lorem imperdiet sit` string word by word and I will give each category a value, depending on how many of the string words are present in the category's 'dominating words'. i.e.:

Category1 will have value of 3 (lorem) + 2 (sit), and Category2 will have a value of 0 (no matches between the split words of the string I am categorizing and the dominating words in the category). The highest-value category 'wins'.

In short, my algorithm is:

1. Use levenshtein distance with a threshold of allowing 1/5th of the string to change, to find the closest matching rule.
2. If it fails, split the string we are categorizing into words and with each word, check how 'dominating' that word is in each category, creating a value for the category. The highest value category is our best guess.

Is there a better way to do this? Do you see a problem with this algorithm? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem with the algorithm. However, I do think there may be a problem behind the question.

No algorithm, provided they are correctly implemented, will present a problem per se. It is the use we make of them under the circumstances of a particular *domain* that would give appropriate or inappropriate results.

Therefore, instead of trying to find the best algorithm you can think of, I would advise you to put your algorithm at practice in the particular situation you are considering. It is that kind of exercise, and not the algorithm as an isolated entity, what will provide you with insights about the limitations and strengths of a given solution. In other words, do not pursue an abstract perfection beforehand. Implement the simplest solution that might work and then keep improving as you learn more.